# Linq to Entities: How to copy records from one table to another efficiently?

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

We have an event system which organizes data by date and time.  We frequently copy data from the old event to the new event as a starter, then modify it.

This is what we do in Linq:

- Get the source objects locally with .ToList()
- For each item create a new object
- Copy the non-primary key values to the new object and set the new primary key
- Add that object to the table

This generates a tremendous amount of database calls.  It's wrapped in a transaction at least.

This is the statement in SQL.  Any way to make Linq that efficient without embedding SQL?

```
insert into targetTable (eventID, two, three, four five)
select @newEventId as eventID, two, three, four, five
from   targetTable 
where  eventid = @eventid
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't make the EF code more efficient. It is how EF works. If you want efficiency wrap your SQL into stored procedure, map stored procedure in EF designer and call that SP.

If you can't create stored procedure then execute SQL directly. You can use:

```
ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(...)
```

This method is only available in EF4.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue but our client won't allow us to alter their schema.  Not a problem until you need to create stored procedures.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: I added some alternative. It is not nice but if you want efficiency you have no better choice then calling SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep it as efficient, you will need to put your SQL into a stored procedure and then add that stored procedure to your entity data model.

Comment: Good idea, but our customer won't let us modify the underlying database.

Comment: Oh, well that should have been included in the question. You will probably have to just embed the SQL for now and push someone (perhaps a DBA that actually has rights) to add the stored proc later to the database for maintainability.